# asm/system.h header file linux

Tags: linux, drivers, headers

I am trying to install drivers for fax modem, and I have tried different ways to do it, but each way leads me to an error which says:

```
fatal error: asm/system.h: No such file or directory
```

Is there some way to solve this?

EDIT:
On a CD which came with my drivers, there is v.1.0 version of dgcmodem driver (http://www.linuxant.com/drivers/dgc/downloads.php), and I tried to install that version and also the newest version (found in mentioned link), and I got that error.
Also I tried to install hsfmodem drivers (http://www.linuxant.com/drivers/hsf/oem/downloads.php), and I got the same error.

Answer (score 9):

This file was removed in Linux 3.4, commit [f05e798ad4c0](https://git.kernel.org/linus/f05e798ad4c09255f590f5b2c00a7ca6c172f983); its contents have been moved into various other headers.

It's *possible* that just removing the `#include <asm/system.h>` might work, but it's much more likely that your driver is simply incompatible with current Linux versions.

Comment: The thing is, the driver I got is the latest driver for that hardware. If it is as you say, then I am highly disappointed in linux.

Comment: Why  not the Unix /Linux stack exchange

Comment: @xpg94 disappointed for not maintaining a proprietary driver for obsolete hardware? You should blame it on the proprietors of the driver, then, not on Linux. We, as a community, cannot be held responsible for **not** maintaining proprietary software.

Comment: @MariusMatutiae I suppose you're right.

Comment: @xpg94 Why don't you tell us which driver you are trying to compile? Other people have gotten around the problem, one way or another.

Comment: On a CD which came with my drivers, there is v.1.0 version of dgcmodem driver (http://www.linuxant.com/drivers/dgc/downloads.php), and I tried to install that version and also the newest version (found in mentioned link).
Also I tried to install hsfmodem drivers (http://www.linuxant.com/drivers/hsf/oem/downloads.php), and I get the same error.

Answer (score 2):

As a matter of fact, there seems to be a patch for your driver. You will find it discussed [in this Ubuntu Forum post](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1939787). Mind you, the discussion is 6 pages long... at some point a guy called `linktopower` provides a patch that allows compilation. The patch is provided through a file, uploaded to the net several times as the guy shuffles providers. The last link is provided [at page 6](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1939787&p=12941004#post12941004), and it is still active.

The patch allows compilation against the kernel in Ubuntu 12.04, so most likely it would be a 3.2 kernel. You may try going down this road.

Comment: When I try to patch using this command:
sudo patch -p1 < dgcmodem-1.13.patch
I get this output (Don't know what to type in now):
can't find file to patch at input line 4
Perhaps you used the wrong -p or --strip option?
The text leading up to this was:
--------------------------
|diff -ur dgcmodem-1.13-old/modules/mod_dgcusbdcp.c dgcmodem-1.13-new/modules/mod_dgcusbdcp.c
|--- dgcmodem-1.13-old/modules/mod_dgcusbdcp.c 2010-03-25 10:31:18.000000000 -0700
|+++ dgcmodem-1.13-new/modules/mod_dgcusbdcp.c 2012-07-25 22:30:08.366214038 -0700
--------------------------
File to patch:

Comment: I placed the patch into the same directory, and the patching was successful.
But after installation, when I enter dgcconfig, to finlaize the installation, I get the same error I had before patching the file.

Answer (score 0):

Go to ...arch/{x86,arm64,etc}/include/asm/system{_misc,_types}.h

It'll depened upon architecture you're building for and also system.h may've been split into system_misc.h and system_types.h

Then, replace `<asm/system.h>` in the faulty .c for `"full/path/to/your/newly/found/asm/system_misc.h"`

Comment: This looks like half an answer. What should the OP ***do**?*